# Changing the background color of a CFWindow

Tags: extjs, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

ColdFusion defaults CFWindows to a dull grey backgorund, I believe hex value #dddddd.  I would like to change this, which seems to be best done using the bodyStyle attribute.  However, I'm creating the window using the javaScript method:

```
 ColdFusion.Window.create('#attributes.name#','#attributes.title#',windowURL#caller.windowID#,dFeatures);
```

Adding bodyStyle to the dFeatures variable does not have any effect, and the CF documentation indicates no way to pass a style in using this method.

Is it possible to (easily) change the background color of a CFWindow when not creating the CFWindow with a tag?

Comment: Give this CSS code a try.  I stylize my window through CSS code instead of the call. .x-window-mc {
background-color: #dddddd;
}

Comment: Steve, absolutely perfect.  Could you please add that as an answer that I can accept so you receive credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this CSS code a try. I stylize my window through CSS code instead of the call.

```
.x-window-mc { background-color: #dddddd; }
```

Comment: This code was included within our custom tag to apply on all pages with cfWindows and worked perfectly.